# paper-drawer-panel vs app-drawer in Polymer

Tags: polymer

`paper-drawer-panel` and `app-drawer` both seem to have similar functionality in Polymer. What is the difference between these elements and when should one be used over the other?

Thanks

Comment: The paper element set are those which conform to Google's Material Design whereas the app elements don't and are for apps that won't need to have the look and feel of Google's Material Design.

Comment: Ok. Do you know if there is a reason why these weren't consolidated into one element where the "Material Design" styling could have been applied via an opt-in basis? Also if this is an answer, could you submit this as an answer rather than a comment? Thanks

Comment: [This](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout) link should explain things a bit better!

Answer (score 2):

The paper element set are those which conform to Google's Material Design whereas the app elements don't and are for apps that won't need to have the look and feel of Google's Material Design.

From the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/toolbox/app-layout):

> ... these elements are designed to be:
>
> - More flexible and composable -- supporting a wider range of layout patterns.
> - Less opinionated -- these elements don't enforce a particular look and feel (although they still support the Material Design effects and UI patterns if that's what you're looking for).
> - Extensible -- with a new, pluggable system for scroll effects.

Comment: So basically if I want material design I should opt for paper-drawer and Im gonna have a leaner component ?

Comment: Yes, I'd go with the paper elements if you want a look and feel that follows the material design guidelines.